# append tf.ones and tf.zeros (tensorflow)

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, classification

my dumb code:

```
ones = [1 for i in range(len(positivePictures))]
zeros = [0 for i in range(len(negativePictuers))]
y = zeros + ones
classes = np.array(y).reshape(1,len(y))
```

this works but it's taking too long (about 4k pictures). I was thinking about using

tf.ones and tf.zeros instead.

But I don't know how to append two tensors together. I know I can evaluate the result to get back a numpy array. But How to append them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UHHHHHG. 
I hate having to answer my own question.

```
def getOnesAndZeros(num_ones, num_zeros):

        sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
            ones = tf.ones(
                (num_ones, 1),
                dtype=tf.float32,
                name=None
            )
            zeros = tf.zeros(
                (num_zeros, 1),
                dtype=tf.float32,
                name=None
            )

            both = tf.concat([ones, zeros], 0)
            npBoth = both.eval()
            return npBoth.flatten()
```